# Looking on a how to have a responsive image in background that rest of page float over

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am designing a responsive website and pretty much have it built, but notice that one website i visited http://www.diversant.com has an image that the rest of the webpage seems to float over. I search over and over to find the solution using w3.css but nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `background-size:cover` for responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.class-name {
    background-image: url(imageurl);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
 }
```

1. background-size:cover for responsiveness.
2. background-attachment:fixed to fix it, image will not scroll than with content.

Comment: Thanks for both answer. Great

Answer (score 0):

You can add `background-image:url(image.jpg)` and then make `background-attachment: fixed;`